# How to group by a column and show as one row

Tags: oracle, group-by, string-aggregation

I have a table with following structure

```
SubId       Status  
---------------------------------------
001         Active
001         Partially Active
```

While displaying this record, I need to display this like this

```
SubId   Status  
---------------------------------------
001     Active/Partially active
```

I tried using distinct, but this returns both rows.

Any idea how can I get only 1 row instead of 2. I know it would be simple. I just cannot find it.

Comment: If you search for string aggregation, you'll get plenty of examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select subid, 
       listagg(status, '/') within group (order by null) as status
from the_table
group by subid;
```